# MYSQL CTE Checking for Circular Reference on managerial hierarchy but not getting any output

Tags: mysql, recursive-query, circular-reference

I have two columns, one for employee position IDs and one for Manager position.
Iam trying to check for any circular reference within the hierarchy structure but I am not getting any output. I also need to make sure the query is good enough to account for large amount of position data as well. Please help and here is my code

```
WITH RECURSIVE FindRoot AS
(
    SELECT EE_Position,Manager_Position, CAST(EE_Position AS CHAR(500)) Path, 0 Distance
    FROM Manger_Table
  
    UNION ALL
   
    SELECT C.EE_Position, P.Manager_Position, CONCAT(C.Path,' > ',CAST(P.EE_Position AS CHAR(500))), C.Distance + 1
    FROM Manger_Table P
    JOIN FindRoot C
    ON C.Manager_Position = P.EE_Position AND P.Manager_Position <> P.EE_Position AND C.Manager_Position <> C.EE_Position
 )
SELECT *
FROM FindRoot R
WHERE R.EE_Position = R.Manager_Position 
  AND R.Manager_Position <> 0
  AND R.Distance > 0;
```

Can someone also please teach me if it does detect a circular reference, how do we display it? like CASE WHEN x = x then 'Circular Reference Detected' as 'Error Message'?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO

```
-- test table
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,   -- entity
  ref INT   -- its parent
  );
```

```
CREATE VIEW test_for_circle
  AS
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT id, ref, CAST('' AS CHAR(1024)) AS path
  FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT test.id, test.ref, CONCAT_WS(',', cte.path, cte.id)
  FROM cte
  JOIN test ON cte.ref = test.id
  WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(cte.id, cte.path)
)
-- SELECT * FROM cte
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM cte
                WHERE FIND_IN_SET(cte.id, cte.path)
                ) circle_found
```

```
-- test data w/o circle reference
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 3);
SELECT * FROM test_for_circle;
```

| circle_found |
| --- |
| 0 |

```
-- add circle reference
INSERT INTO test VALUES (7,8), (8,9), (9,7);
SELECT * FROM test_for_circle;
```

| circle_found |
| --- |
| 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PwgdA2it)

Comment: Based on your code sample, how do make it display which id and ref showing circlar reference? SELECT id, ref, case when(cte.ref = test.id) THEN 'circular reference detected' ELSE '' END?

Comment: @Code_Journey_4_Fun Replace current outer query with commented one and investigate the output.